# yet another number of islands

Tags: python, python-3.x

i learn python and i am at beginner level in python

TL`DR
i did NOT read the other questions concerning this topic since i try to learn python and therefore need to do the same stoopid errors others have done to improve my knowlegde. And since i know other things than the other OPs is my code somehow different

---

**class Field (in `islands.py`)**

```
class Field:
  def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, isWater):
    self.xpos = xpos
    self.ypos = ypos
    self.isWater = isWater

  def __str__(self):
    iswater = "W" if self.isWater else "L" 
    return f"{self.xpos}/{self.ypos}/{iswater}"
  
  def isAdjected(self, anotherField):
    if anotherField is None:
      return False

    if not isinstance(anotherField, Field):
      return False

    if anotherField.xpos == self.xpos and anotherField.ypos+1 == self.ypos:
      return True
    
    if anotherField.xpos == self.xpos and anotherField.ypos-1 == self.ypos:
      return True
    
    if anotherField.xpos+1 == self.xpos and anotherField.ypos == self.ypos:
      return True
    
    if anotherField.xpos-1 == self.xpos and anotherField.ypos == self.ypos:
      return True
      
    return False
```

**class Map (in `islands.py`)**

```
class Map:
  def __init__(self, data:list): 
    x = 0
    self.fields = list()
    for row in data:
      y = 0
      for column in row:
        a_field = Field(x,y,column=='0')
        self.fields.append(a_field)
        y = y + 1
      x = x + 1 

  def __str__(self):
    return f"island data={self.fields}"
  
  def calculate_number_of_islands(self) -> int: 
    print ("removing all water fields")
    candidates = list(filter(lambda field : not field.isWater, self.fields)) 
    
    islandcounter = 0  
    while len(candidates) > 0 :
      candidate = candidates.pop(0)
      print (f"popping next field {candidate} and expanding an island")
      self.expand_land(candidate, candidates) 
      islandcounter = islandcounter + 1

    return islandcounter
  
  def expand_land(self, candidate, candidates):
    print ("getting neighbour fields") 
    neighbours = list(filter(lambda field : field.isAdjected(candidate), candidates)) 

    for neighbour in neighbours:       
      print (f"  adding {neighbour}")      
      if(neighbour in candidates):
        candidates.remove(neighbour)
        self.expand_land(neighbour, candidates)
        
    return None
```

**main method**

```
import island_parser
import island

#https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/description/

csvFile = 'resources\\island_01.csv'
data = island_parser.read_csv(csvFile)

island_map = island.Map(data)
number_of_islands = island_map.calculate_number_of_islands()
print (f"this map has {number_of_islands} islands")
```

**note**
i did not include the data parser to parse an csv into a `List<List<String>>` that is not part of the review

data is a `List<List<String>>` where each `String` is either `0` (water) or `1` (land), example here:

```
1,1,0,1,0
1,1,1,1,0
0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,1
```

resulting in an number of 3 islands

any comments welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## python != java

```
    self.isWater = isWater
```

In `Field`, [pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you name it `is_water`.

Also, please use [black](https://pypi.org/project/black) to format your code.
The two-space indent is distracting, makes it look like blocks were pasted in
from another language.

---

## optional type hinting

```
  def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, isWater):
```

You don't *have* to.
But it would be a kindness to the Gentle Reader to offer the types:

```
  def __init__(self, xpos: float, ypos: float, isWater: str):
```

(A ctor always returns `None` -- you can throw in `... ) -> None:` if you like.)

I'm sad we're accepting `str` instead of `bool` (which is a kind of `int`).
The data parser adheres to a rather peculiar contract.
If you had instead relied on the usual
[.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
we would have obtained rows of integers
just through the default behavior.

Consider using a
[@property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)
decorator for the {'L', 'W'} mapping:

```
    iswater = "W" if self.isWater else "L"
```

Whatever you do, please don't use the names `iswater` and `isWater`
to represent distinct concepts.
Invent a *new* name, perhaps `terrain`.
It doesn't matter to the machine, but it *does* affect human cognition.
To say nothing of making telephone conversations more difficult
when we're discussing some code.

---

## use standard English

```
  def isAdjected(self, anotherField):
```

Instead of `is_adjected` I think you intended `is_adjacent` ?

```
    if anotherField is None:
      return False
```

I'm going to second-guess this design choice.
In my opinion it probably makes sense to `assert` that it's not `None`,
or otherwise document / insist that caller is responsible for passing
in an actual `Field` object.
The rationale is fear of a `False` return value masking some caller bug.

```
    if not isinstance(anotherField, Field):
      return False
```

The previous test is redundant with this one, as `None` is definitely not a `Field`.
And again, if this triggers I feel it is probably due to caller violating the
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).
What I'm driving at is, spell out the contract, then hold the caller to it.

Notice that we are *not* playing by the
[total ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)
rules that are required to e.g. sort() a `list`.
You invented your own method name,
so you get to make up whatever rules you find convenient
for the task at hand.

```
    if anotherField.xpos == self.xpos and anotherField.ypos+1 == self.ypos:
      ...    
    if anotherField.xpos == self.xpos and anotherField.ypos-1 == self.ypos:
      ...    
    if anotherField.xpos+1 == self.xpos and anotherField.ypos == self.ypos:
      ...    
    if anotherField.xpos-1 == self.xpos and anotherField.ypos == self.ypos:
```

Ok, that's just tedious.

If you *really* want to follow that approach, at least define a vector
of delta-coordinate tuples:

```
    for dx, dy in [(0, 1),
                   (0, -1),
                   (1, 0),
                   (-1, 0)]:
```

But wouldn't it be more convenient to `def distance` which returns the
L1-norm [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)
between the pair?
Then you can just ask if it is exactly `1`.

---

## shadowing builtins

```
class Map:
```

This is a lovely identifier, thank you.
Fair warning, in python land
we try to avoid assigning to `map`, as there is already a
[map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) in the
[builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) functions.
The convention is to append a trailing `_` underscore to avoid shadow meanings:

- `map_`
- `list_`
- `dir_`
- `id_`

and so on.
(Yeah, my apologies, python is a "small" language, but regrettably a bunch
of common identifiers are already taken.)

The identifier `Map` is distinct from `map`,
and is unlikely to cause confusion on the telephone,
so this is perfect as-is.

---

## optional type hinting

```
class Map:
  def __init__(self, data: list): 
    ...
    self.fields = list()
```

Yay, type annotations, kudos, very nice.

It definitely *is* valuable to know we're dealing with a list,
especially for such an uninformative name as "data", so I thank you for that.
However, for extra credit, you can *also* tell us what's inside the list:

```
  def __init__(self, data: list[Field]):
```

Without that, linting with
[mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy)
will be somewhat less informative,
as the `list` in the signature and the `... = list()` assignment
both have type `list[Any]`.

```
        a_field = Field(x, y, column == '0')
```

That's an OK name, but somewhat unusual in this ecosystem.
Prefer to simply call it `field = Field( ... )`.

```
        y = y + 1
      x = x + 1
```

Gentle reminder: There's no `++` increment operator, but we *do* have `y += 1`.

We seem to have a list-of-lists datastructure representing terrain,
and that is perfectly fine.
Please understand that there *are* alternatives.

A list of N elements costs N+1 pointers, which typically will be 64-bit pointers.
One for the list, plus one for each object pointed at.
So we represent the booleans `[1, 0, 1]` with *significantly* more than three bits.

Python offers [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)
to efficiently store lots of things that have identical type.
And if you go there, you're likely to go all the way to
[numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy)'s
[NDarrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html),
since they offer a great many convenience functions right out of the box.
For example, filtering down to adjacent cells becomes very convenient.
Storing N booleans in either kind of array
will typically cost slighty more than 8 × N bits.
That is, one byte per element is usual.
If N is inconveniently large, consider using a
[bit vector](https://pypi.org/project/BitVector).

---

## docstrings

```
  def expand_land(self, candidate, candidates):
    print ("getting neighbour fields") 
    neighbours = list(filter(lambda field : field.isAdjected(candidate), candidates)) 

    for neighbour in neighbours:       
      print (f"  adding {neighbour}")      
      if(neighbour in candidates):
        candidates.remove(neighbour)
        self.expand_land(neighbour, candidates)
        
    return None
```

This is a nice little recursive helper, thank you for breaking it out.
A bit chatty perhaps, but I'm sure we can elide the debugs
once things are working, or else use a
[logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) at DEBUG severity.

Feel free to have the signature end with `...) -> None:`

This method definitely needs a """docstring"""
which explains that we mutate the final argument.

The `return None` at the end is weird; please elide it.
Certainly it is *accurate*.
But we don't write it explicitly when the intent is to evaluate for side effects.
As written, it looks as though the method is supposed to return some useful value,
and if it was a hundred-line method I would have to read through its various
`if` clauses to see if `return 42` appeared elsewhere.
Consider the one-line `def greet` which prints Hello world.
We don't make it a two-liner by finishing with `return None`.
We let python implicitly do that.

## use appropriate datastructure

```
      if(neighbour in candidates):
```

First, this isn't java, please prefer:

```
      if neighbour in candidates:
```

Second, if I recall correctly, `candidates` is a `list`.
Please understand that `in` will linearly scan the container,
so we're probably looking at quadratic cost here.

Consider using a `set` for the candidates.
Note that only hashable (typically immutable)
elements can be stored in sets, or as `dict` keys,
so sometimes it takes a bit of rejiggering to switch
to a more efficient container.

---

## quoting

```
csvFile = 'resources\\island_01.csv'
```

Uggh!

Prefer a raw string:

```
csv_file = r'resources\island_01.csv'
```

Or, to be even more expressive of Author's Intent:

```
from pathlib import Path

csv_file = Path('resources/island_01.csv')
```

(You could give it a `\` backwhack instead of a `/` slash, it would be the same.)

---

Welcome to python land!

Recommend you routinely rely on tools like

- [black](https://pypi.org/project/black)
- [isort](https://pypi.org/project/black)
- [mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy)
- python [-m unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase), or [pytest](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-cov)

to tidy up your source and keep it in good working order.

This codebase appears to achieve its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: well. that was the very desired input i needed, thank you so much - all those beginner mistakes brought straight to the point :-) that is really valuable input for me. sadly i cannot +2, because if i could i would +5 your answer!! great!

Comment: Great, happy to help!

Comment: man - **python != java** its really hard to switch! i understand how it should be but i always fall back into my java style ^^ (hahah 20 years of experience have left their mark ^^, oh yes, since java 1.2)